# Implement early stopping in emcee given a convergence criterion

Tags: python, mcmc, emcee

I am using `emcee.EnsembleSampler` to sample some likelihoods. I am doing this on millions of different data sets, and so performance is important.

It would be great to be able to get a chain to stop sampling once it has satisfied some convergence criterion on the autocorrelation time.

I can not find any way of doing this in the documentation, or through my searches, so was hoping someone has a recipe for it.

Answer (score 3):

While I too couldn't find anything in the current emcee docs, the latest versions seems to have added a tutorial which happens to show the exact thing you are trying to do: [link](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/monitor/)

In case the link breaks or things change, here is the example:

```
import emcee
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

# The definition of the log probability function
# We'll also use the "blobs" feature to track the "log prior" for each step
def log_prob(theta):
    log_prior = -0.5 *  np.sum((theta-1.0)**2 / 100.0)
    log_prob = -0.5 * np.sum(theta**2) + log_prior
    return log_prob, log_prior

# Initialize the walkers
coords = np.random.randn(32, 5)
nwalkers, ndim = coords.shape

# Set up the backend
# Don't forget to clear it in case the file already exists
filename = "tutorial.h5"
backend = emcee.backends.HDFBackend(filename)
backend.reset(nwalkers, ndim)

# Initialize the sampler
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_prob, backend=backend)

max_n = 100000

# We'll track how the average autocorrelation time estimate changes
index = 0
autocorr = np.empty(max_n)

# This will be useful to testing convergence
old_tau = np.inf

# Now we'll sample for up to max_n steps
for sample in sampler.sample(coords, iterations=max_n, progress=True):
    # Only check convergence every 100 steps
    if sampler.iteration % 100:
        continue

    # Compute the autocorrelation time so far
    # Using tol=0 means that we'll always get an estimate even
    # if it isn't trustworthy
    tau = sampler.get_autocorr_time(tol=0)
    autocorr[index] = np.mean(tau)
    index += 1

    # Check convergence
    converged = np.all(tau * 100 < sampler.iteration)
    converged &= np.all(np.abs(old_tau - tau) / tau < 0.01)
    if converged:
        break
    old_tau = tau
```

Comment: Dear Sebastian, Could I have your email address, please?  I would like to ask you about one problem in EMCEE I ran into.